# Validator::validateNumber does not exist

Tags: laravel, validation

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1OfF.png)
[image]

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxFBT.png)
[image]

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vdN3.png)
[image]

Why is post request not allowed?

Answer (score 7):

Use `numeric` instead `number`

```
commisionRate => "required|numeric|between:0,0.99",
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Laravel default validation rules which are here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules

there are no rule for "number"

according to your third screenshot you are using number validation rules just remove it.

```
commisionRate => "required|number|min:0.01|max:1
```

to this

```
commisionRate => "required|min:0.01|max:1
```

check your all fiels and do this change. To check number laravel provide you "numeric" validation rules